# Opacity problem in MSIE

Tags: jquery, css

This works in FF, Chrome and other browsers except IE8:

```
<span class="cart_warning">Please select a color</span>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.cart_warning').css({opacity: 0, color: '000000'});
</script>
```

In IE8 the color changes to black but opacity doesn't. What could be the problem? There are no transparent PNGs involved.

Comment: additional info ,if you are doing in runtime you can use jquery  if($.browser.msie){} otherwise you can specify the same in css file for IE

Answer (score 1):

you'll need to use the IE-specific version: `filter:alpha(opacity=0);`
though I'm not sure jQuery's gonna let you set that easily. I'd probably make that a class and do a `addClass()`

Comment: opacity via CSS should work in IE8, it works on other pages, it works if I set opacity for some other item on the page but for this span it doesn't work

Comment: Hrm, I thought jQuery took care of the filter when you change the opacity...I guess it's only for the fade__() methods.

Comment: opacity works fine for other elements on the page, just not for this span... that's what's weird

Comment: Perhaps there is some other rule overriding it on your page.

Comment: well I don't know what that could be. setting opacity for other spans doesn't work, however it works for every other element. What could be overriding jquery setting this (and only this) property in (and only in) IE8?

Answer (score 0):

Got it. The problem was haslayout, that is the spans that I was trying to change opacity for didn't have layout and that was the problem in IE8 only. Hmm...